# retrieve records between fromdate and todate passing two dates and foreign key value in MYSQL or HQL

Tags: mysql, hql

retrieve records  between fromdate and todate passing two date and foreign key value.
 [image]

i tried this,

```
SELECT* FROM Test where T_ID = 1 and '2015-03-10' BETWEEN FROM_DATE and TO_DATE or '2015-03-18' BETWEEN FROM_DATE and TO_DATE;
```

but it returns  foreign key records with another foreign key records between these dates

the correct result size should be 2. 
but here returns 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T_ID is no given in second part of the query.

```
select * from Test where T_ID = 1 and '2015-03-10' BETWEEN FROM_DATE and TO_DATE or T_ID = 1 and'2015-03-18' BETWEEN FROM_DATE and TO_DATE;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to organize your `OR` clause in `()`

```
SELECT* FROM Test
 where T_ID = 1 
and ('2015-03-10' BETWEEN FROM_DATE and TO_DATE 
or '2015-03-18' BETWEEN FROM_DATE and TO_DATE);
```